# IBM BPM create a Task when action is called

Tags: javascript, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

How we can create a manuall Task (adhoc Task) and assign it to a User when some actions are triggered (e.g. when the Service is called)?

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc tasks run in the context of a BPD.  What is the connection between the service you are calling and the Ad-Hoc task?  Generally the ad-hoc events are meant to be triggered by a participant in the process selecting the item they want to launch.

If what you want is that an external system triggers an event in a running instance when certain things happen you might want to look at Intermediate Message Events (IMEs).  To really provide the correct full answer we likely need to have a better understanding of the underlying use case in order to guide you well.

Answer (score 0):

From your answer I am not able to find you doing it on BPD level or Service level.
If you are doing on BPD level then you can use intermediate event to call that Activity attached to that service.you can configure whether you want to fire that event or not on previous human service using UCA.